# What is the best way to debug a `segfault-ing` monero daemon on ubuntu

Tags: monerod, full-node, development

Does it require compiling a `debug` build, or can it be done with a `release` build as well? I assume it can be done, but might lack proper feedback!?

Either way; which tools are needed and which guidelines should i follow?

For example, would;

> gdb monerod
>   run
>   -*segfault*-
>   bt

Generate enough information for the devs to work with? Or are there better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right steps, but a release build will not provide enough info so it would be better to compile a debug build.

Comment: Makes sense!
Would i also be able to locate and pinpoint `libboost` problems? And is there any need for loading libraries that supply symbols, or would a `debug` build achieve that?

Comment: A debug build shouldn't need any other libraries, in general. libboost - maybe. Half of libboost is header files, so those bits will be debuggable. Half is external libraries, so for those parts you'd need debug libraries.